# Find $c$ to make $f(x) = ce^{-ax}$ a probability density.

Tags: probability

> For some value of $c$, $f(x) = ce^{-ax}; x > 0; a > 0$ is a probability
>   density function. Find $c$.

How can I find $c$? Like any suggestions from where I can  begin

Comment: This is related to the normalizing constant.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Comment: So like what should the steps be. I belive it should be and indefinite integral from -infiteive to postive infitve, but then what?

Comment: Depressing question

Comment: I solved it for you qwe in details below.

Answer (score 2):

Density functions satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=1$. Try integrating your function and solving for $c$.

Answer (score 1):

To check your answer/alternatively,
if you have studied the exponential distribution up to this point, then 
recognize that
$$e^{-ax}$$
is ***almost*** the exponential density. 
You need to multiply it by a factor of $a$; hence $c = a$.

I recommend to keep this kind of thinking in mind for future problems. It can be handy.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is a probability density function then:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1.$$

In your case we have

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\ dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}0\ dx+\int_{0}^{+\infty}c\cdot e^{-ax}dx=0+\int_{0}^{+\infty}c\cdot e^{-ax}dx=\lim_{M\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{M}c\cdot e^{-ax}dx$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{M\to+\infty}\left[-\frac{c}{a}e^{-ax}\right]^{M}_{0}=\lim_{M\to+\infty}\left(-\frac{c}{a}e^{-a\cdot M}-\left(-\frac{c}{a}e^{-a\cdot 0}\right)\right)=\lim_{M\to+\infty}\left(-\frac{c}{a}e^{-a\cdot M}+\frac{c}{a}\right)=\frac{c}{a}$,

so we get $\frac{c}{a}=1$ and finally $c=a$.

Note that:

I. $\displaystyle \int c\cdot e^{-ax}\ dx=-\frac{c}{a}e^{-ax}+C$, where $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

II. $\displaystyle \lim_{M\to+\infty}\left(-\frac{c}{a}e^{-a\cdot M}\right)=\lim_{M\to+\infty}\left(-\frac{c}{a}\frac{1}{e^{a\cdot M}}\right)=\left[-\frac{c}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{+\infty}\right]=\left[-\frac{c}{a}\cdot 0\right]=0$,

since $a>0$.